# 17.10 DNS problems

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

It seems that my installation started to fail sometime after an update. 
I also have a 16.04 installation as well as Win10 which work fine.

It APPEARS to be a DNS problem, in that I can ping addresses but not domain names successfully, and nslookup succeeds ONLY if I specify a nameserver.

The odd thing is that I've added "DNS=8.8.8.8" to my resolved.conf, AND nmcli DOES show a nameserver configured.

This problem occurs both with wireless (and I manually setup addresses to sidestep DHCP without success) as well as ethernet.

So I'm a bit stumped...thank you!

Comment: Well, after spending several hours on this, i determined that the problem had SOMETHING to do, apparently, with netmasq.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after spending several hours on this, i determined that the problem had SOMETHING to do, apparently, with dnsmasq. My etc/resolv.conf file kept being set back to "nameserver 127.0.1.1", which would be for dnsmasq, but I had NO entry in my NetworkManager.conf file referencing it.  Many other people have explicitly commented out such a reference to fix such problems, but in my case I had to ADD that "dns=dnsmasq" to the file and now it is working! I'm still unclear on what the heck is going on, as I see no dnsmasq process running, but I guess Ijust marking it "solved".